# Getting 0 holder on Etherscan testnet despite having token transactions through DAPP

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, metamask, dapps, etherscan

Recently, I've created a token and it is pure ERC-20 Compliant...I've sent some token to another address but when I see it on rinkeby testnet etherscan web page it shows 0 holder despite having  the transaction in transaction section below...Moreover, when I try to view token in metamask, Metamask also showed, we had trouble loading your token balance...What I'm missing here ??

Here's my code:

```
contract myToken {
  address payable owner;
  string public name = "Test TOKEN";
  string public symbol = "TT";
  uint public totalSupply_;
  uint public tokenSold;
  uint8 public decimals = 0;
  uint256 public token_price = 300000000000000;
  uint256 public token_incremental_price = 0;
  uint256 public currentPrice;

  event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint tokens);
  event Approval(address indexed _tokenOwner, address indexed _spender, uint tokens);


  constructor(uint initialSupply) public  {
    owner = msg.sender;
    totalSupply_ = initialSupply * 10**uint256(decimals);
    totalSupply_ = initialSupply;
    tokenLedger[owner] = totalSupply_;
    currentPrice = token_price + token_incremental_price;
}

mapping(address => uint) internal tokenLedger;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowed;

function myTokens() public view returns(uint256) {
    return balanceOf(msg.sender);
}

function balanceOf(address _customerAddress) public
    view
    returns(uint)
{
    return tokenLedger[_customerAddress];
}


function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
      return totalSupply_;
}

 function transfer(address _toAddress, uint256 _amountOfTokens)
    public
    returns(bool success)
   {
    address _customerAddress = msg.sender;
    require(_amountOfTokens <= tokenLedger[_customerAddress] && _amountOfTokens > 0);

    tokenLedger[_customerAddress] = SafeMath.sub(tokenLedger[_customerAddress], _amountOfTokens);
    tokenLedger[_toAddress] = SafeMath.add(tokenLedger[_toAddress], _amountOfTokens);
    emit Transfer(_customerAddress, _toAddress, _amountOfTokens);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 tokens) public returns(bool success)  {
    require(tokens <= tokenLedger[_from]);
    require(tokens > 0);
    require(tokens <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);        
    tokenLedger[_from] = SafeMath.sub(tokenLedger[_from], tokens);
    tokenLedger[_to] = SafeMath.add(tokenLedger[_to], tokens);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = SafeMath.sub(allowed[_from][msg.sender], tokens);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, tokens);
    return true;
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _tokens) public returns(bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _tokens;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _tokens);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns(uint256 remaining) 
{
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}
```

Comment: What's the token address? Did you register the source code on etherscan? On etherscan testnet aren't updated quickly, so perhaps after some hours it will appear as a token.

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with your code:

1. It doesn't compile. Related to at least the `}` on about line 10 which closes the contract too soon
2. It's not ERC20 compliant. The contract is missing at least function `transferFrom` (it's named wrong in your code)
3. It's missing the event signatures.

Comment: on line 10, it was a typo.. One point, I forgot to mention is I'm purchasing and selling token through DAPP..Transactions are showing in the etherscan but the token holder remain 0..

Comment: I have reconfigured the code..it had events and the contract was closed by typo in the stack exchange..